# Regular expression to find last group in python

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I want to find last group in following text.See example below

Input string

**str1** = "Calculate fuel economy, lease, or mortgage payments Click the View menu, point to Worksheets, and then click the worksheet for the calculation you want.br_tag 2.Under Select the value you want  to calculate, click the variable that you want to calculate..br_tag 3.Enter the known values in the text boxes and then click Calculate..br_tag"

**output i want**

```
..br_tag
```

str2 = "Calculate fuel economy, lease, or mortgage payments Click the View menu, point to Worksheets, and then click the worksheet for the calculation you want.br_tag 2.Under Select the value you want  to calculate, click the variable that you want to calculate..br_tag 3.Enter the known values in the text boxes and then click Calculate..br_tag br_tag"

**output i want**

```
..br_tag br_tag
```

**I tried using**

```
re.compile(r'(\w\.(.*?))$')
```

**But here i get output as**

> t.br_tag 2.Under Select the value you want  to calculate, click the
>   variable that you want to calculate..br_tag 3.Enter the known values
>   in the text boxes and then click Calculate..br_tag br_tag

Comment: Can you elaborate better on the expected output? Are you using `group(1)` and `group(2)` or just `group(2)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the regex greedy feature to match all the characters as much as possible. So `.*\w\.` matches all the chracaters from the start upto the last dot which was preceded by a word character. Now, `.*\w(\..*)$` would capture all the characters from the last dot which was preceded by a word character.

```
>>> str1 = "Calculate fuel economy, lease, or mortgage payments Click the View menu, point to Worksheets, and then click the worksheet for the calculation you want.br_tag 2.Under Select the value you want to calculate, click the variable that you want to calculate..br_tag 3.Enter the known values in the text boxes and then click Calculate..br_tag"
>>> str2 = "Calculate fuel economy, lease, or mortgage payments Click the View menu, point to Worksheets, and then click the worksheet for the calculation you want.br_tag 2.Under Select the value you want to calculate, click the variable that you want to calculate..br_tag 3.Enter the known values in the text boxes and then click Calculate..br_tag br_tag"
>>> re.search(r'.*\w(\..*)$', str2).group(1)
'..br_tag br_tag'
>>> re.search(r'.*\w(\..*)$', str1).group(1)
'..br_tag'
>>> str3 = "Calculate fuel economy, lease, or mortgage payments Click the View menu, point to Worksheets, and then click the worksheet for the calculation you want.br_tag 2.Under Select the value you want to calculate, click the variable that you want to calculate..br_tag 3.Enter the known values in the text boxes and then click Calculate..br_tag .br_tag"
>>> re.search(r'.*\w(\..*)$', str3).group(1)
'..br_tag .br_tag'
```

**OR**

You could use [lookbehinds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) also.

```
>>> re.search(r'(?<=\w)\.(?:(?<!\w)\.|[^.])*$', str1).group()
'..br_tag'
>>> re.search(r'(?<=\w)\.(?:(?<!\w)\.|[^.])*$', str2).group()
'..br_tag br_tag'
>>> re.search(r'(?<=\w)\.(?:(?<!\w)\.|[^.])*$', str3).group()
'..br_tag .br_tag'
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iX0hS5/1)

Comment: thanx for your reply but if text is "Calculate fuel economy, lease, or mortgage payments Click the View menu, point to Worksheets, and then click the worksheet for the calculation you want.br_tag 2.Under Select the value you want to calculate, click the variable that you want to calculate..br_tag 3.Enter the known values in the text boxes and then click Calculate..br_tag .br_tag"

Comment: what's your expected output for the above? did you want to fetch from the last two dots? explain it clearly.

Comment: actual i want to match from last dot which is preceded by character...output i want is "..br_tag .br_tag"